# How to set compile features in cmake toolchain file for known custom compiler to use target_compile_features

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17

I have minimal **hello world** sample:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

int main(int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/ [])
{
    using namespace std;

    string_view output_phrase("hello world");

    cout << output_phrase << endl;

    bool is_good = cout.good();

    int result = is_good ? EXIT_SUCCESS : EXIT_FAILURE;
    return result;
}
```

So I create minimal **CMakeLists.txt** file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(01-1-hello-world CXX)
add_executable(01-1-hello-world main.cxx)
target_compile_features(01-1-hello-world PUBLIC cxx_std_17)
```

Now If I use known for CMake compiler all works as expected (like MSVC, clang++, g++). But if I try some **custom compiler(based on clang)** from some SDK with **toolchain file** cmake say:

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (target_compile_features):
>    target_compile_features The compiler feature "cxx_std_17" is not known to
>    CXX compiler
>
> "Clang"

So I try to set [`CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES.html#variable:CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES) in my toolchain file

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES cxx_std_17) # we know custom-clang have c++17 support
```

Also I try to set [`CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html) but nothing changes.
How to make `target_compile_features(01-1-hello-world PUBLIC cxx_std_17)` works in toolchain file for cmake for custom compiler? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is in CMakeError.log? Interesting lines are `Detecting CXX [-std=c++17] compiler features failed to compile with the following output:` or something similar.

Comment: i would give [CXX_STANDARD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html#prop_tgt:CXX_STANDARD) a try instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also I try to set CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES

You most probably forgot to *clear* your build tree. Variables in toolchain file are not "refreshed" when you re-run cmake. You have to remove the build files compleatly and reconfigure cmake when making modifications to the toolchain file. It should work. Note that `CMAKE_*_KNOWN_FEATURES` is a *list* of features, o use `list(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES ...)`.

For reference for feature readers and because cmake uses a lot of global variables, I want to post what is working with `sdcc` compiler for C language. For C because it's simpler, it's exactly the same for C++ it's similar with `CXX*` variables. What is the meaning of variables can be deduced from their names.

```
cat > toolchain-sdcc.cmake <<EOF
find_program(CMAKE_C_COMPILER NAMES sdcc)
set(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING TRUE)    
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_DEFAULT "11") # this is the default C standard the compiler uses without any option
set(CMAKE_C90_STANDARD_COMPILE_OPTION "--std-c89")
set(CMAKE_C90_EXTENSION_COMPILE_OPTION "--std-sdcc89")
set(CMAKE_C99_STANDARD_COMPILE_OPTION "--std-c99")
set(CMAKE_C99_EXTENSION_COMPILE_OPTION "--std-sdcc99")
set(CMAKE_C11_STANDARD_COMPILE_OPTION "--std-c11")
set(CMAKE_C11_EXTENSION_COMPILE_OPTION "--std-sdcc11")

list(APPEND CMAKE_C_COMPILE_FEATURES
    c_std_90
    c_std_99
    c_std_11
    c_function_prototypes
    c_restrict
    c_static_assert
    c_variadic_macros
)

EOF
```

```
cat > CMakeLists.txt <<EOF
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE sdcc.cmake)
project(a LANGUAGES C)
file(WRITE a.c "int main() {}")
add_executable(a a.c)
target_compile_features(a PUBLIC
    c_std_90
    c_std_99
    c_std_11
    c_function_prototypes
    c_restrict
    c_static_assert
    c_variadic_macros
)

EOF
```

after that cmake finds the compile features and the project can build.

There is also [`CMakeDetermineCompileFeatures.cmake` that defines `cmake_determine_compile_features`](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompileFeatures.cmake) that is run auto-magically from `project()` call. Then if the macro `cmake_record_c_compile_features` is defined by your toolchain, then that macro is used to determine C language compile features. So you can:

```
cat > toolchain-sdcc.cmake <<EOF
# ...
# remove list(APPEND CMAKE_C_COMPILE_FEATURES, not needed anymore  

# this macro will be called from `project()`
macro(cmake_record_c_compile_features)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_C90_COMPILE_FEATURES c_std_90 c_function_prototypes)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_C99_COMPILE_FEATURES c_std_99 c_restrict c_variadic_macros)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_C11_COMPILE_FEATURES c_std_11 c_static_assert)
    set(_result 0) # expected by cmake_determine_compile_features
endmacro()

EOF
```

After that you will see that well known `Detecting C compile features` message that are generated by `CMakeDetermineCompileFeatures.cmake` when it calls `cmake_record_c_compile_features` macro:

```
$ cmake -S . -B _build
...
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Configuring done
...
```

Last but not least, you can define `CMAKE_C*_STANDARD__HAS_FULL_SUPPORT` macros and use [Compiler/CMakeCommonCompilerMacros](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Compiler/CMakeCommonCompilerMacros.cmake#L65) module that internally defines the `cmake_determine_compile_features` macro, and it checks if `CMAKE_C*_STANDARD__HAS_FULL_SUPPORT` is defines, if it is, it enables all features for that standard of the language:

```
cat > toolchain-sdcc.cmake <<EOF
# ...
set(CMAKE_C90_STANDARD__HAS_FULL_SUPPORT ON)
set(CMAKE_C99_STANDARD__HAS_FULL_SUPPORT ON)
set(CMAKE_C11_STANDARD__HAS_FULL_SUPPORT ON)
# will define cmake_record_c_compile_features macro
# that will inspect CMAKE_C*_STANDARD__HAS_FULL_SUPPORT variables
include(Compiler/CMakeCommonCompilerMacros)
EOF
```

But the real proper place would be to create `Compilers/SDCC-C.cmake` in a `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` paths and put `include(Compiler/CMakeCommonCompilerMacros)` there, like for example [MSVC-CXX.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/Compiler/MSVC-CXX.cmake) does.

Answer (score 0):

```
set_property(TARGET 01-1-hello-world PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

[CXX_STANDARD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html)

Comment: Yes, but I want common solution, it is just sample about cxx_std_17

Comment: It's a common solution, setting the compiler version for a project.

Comment: I think the OP implies that a common solution would be applicable to all of the C++ features in [this list](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html).